# JavaScript Incorrect math

Tags: javascript, math, ieee-754

I have a very very straight forward math problem that is being done. The problem is JavaScript is telling me the wrong answer. After doing some reading, it is related to the 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

However I do not know how to fix the problem really simply.

```
V = 118.3;
X = 22;
Y = 0.05;

z = (X * Y) + V;
```

In this case the answer should be 119.4 but JavaScript is telling me it's 119.39999999999999.

I have been looking but I can not seem to come up with a solution. Does anyone know how to fix, stop, predict, etc this weird "bug" of JavaScript?

Comment: It's not JavaScript, it's binary floating-point math in general.

Comment: It's not just a javascript phenomenon.

Comment: well regardless who or what is at fault how can get around this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3644354/502381

Comment: `Math.ceil(z * 10) / 10` does the trick.